# Error with realm query using NSDate()

Tags: swift, realm

i have this code in swift:

```
lists = sharedAppCore.getRealm().objects(Event).filter("status = 1 OR status = 2").sorted("end_date", ascending: false)
```

now i want to filter with start_date NSDate() but this not work:

```
lists = sharedAppCore.getRealm().objects(Event).filter("status = 1 OR status = 2 OR start_date >= \(NSDate())").sorted("end_date", ascending: false)
```

any ideas?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095950/swift-filter-by-nsdate-object-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved with this code:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "end_date >= %@", NSDate())
lists = sharedAppCore.getRealm().objects(Event).filter("status = 1 OR status = 2").filter(predicate).sorted("end_date", ascending: false)
```

Comment: and if i want to use only date without hour, example: NSPredicate(format: "DATE(end_date) >= %@", NSDate()) ?????

Answer (score 1):

```
lists = sharedAppCore.getRealm()
    .objects(Event)
    .filter("status = 1 OR status = 2 OR start_date >= \(NSDate())")
    .sorted("end_date", ascending: false)
```

Strictly speaking, Above code is not the same as your final code.

```
filter("status = 1 OR status = 2").filter(predicate).sorted("end_date", ascending: false)
```

^ Because this predicate same as the following:

```
filter("(status = 1 OR status = 2) AND end_date >= %@", NSDate())
```

If you create predicate as all `OR`, you can just do the following:

```
filter("status = 1 OR status = 2 OR end_date >= %@", NSDate())
```

Additionally, if you compare without hours, you should truncate hours from the date first. Then compare with the truncated date.

Like the following:

```
let now = NSDate()

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let component = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: now)

let today = calendar.dateFromComponents(component)! // truncated time
```

Then use truncated date to compare in the predicate.

```
let now = NSDate()

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let component = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: now)

let today = calendar.dateFromComponents(component)! // truncated time

let lists = realm
    .objects(Event)
    .filter("status = 1 OR status = 2 OR end_date >= %@", today)
    .sorted("end_date", ascending: false)
```