# How to sort an array of object in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently writing like this

```
static func fromIntervals(intervals: [Interval]) -> ChartData {
    let sortedIntervals = intervals.sorted { (a, b) in return a.startTime < b.startTime}
}
```

But it shows error of

```
Cannot invoke 'sorted' with an argument list of type '((_, _) -> _)'
```

I searched for a lot of other code examples, and none of them work, I have no idea why. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `startTime` an `NSDate`? Then this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577496/how-do-i-sort-a-swift-array-containing-instances-of-nsmanagedobject-subclass-by: `NSDate`s cannot be compared with `<` directly.

Answer (score 1):

it is `sort`not `sorted`

```
let sortedIntervals = intervals.sort { (a, b) in return a.startTime < b.startTime}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. Use `sort` instead of `sorted`.

```
static func fromIntervals(intervals: [Interval]) -> ChartData {
    let sortedIntervals = intervals.sort { (a, b) in return a.startTime < b.startTime}
}
```

### Edit

```
let sortedIntervals = sorted(intervals, { (a: Object, b: Object) -> Bool in return a.startTime < b.startTime } )
```

See [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID95) for more information.

Comment: sort is changing the intervals itself - but that's immutable since it's the parameter of the function. I want another sorted copy.