# Sort my tableView by date swift

Tags: swift, sorting, nsdate, tableview

Anybody can help me with code or hints for sorting my `tableView` according to the date. I think i have to use `NSDate`. I have an array already ready with `NSDate` type instances.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First help us with code… ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This post will most likely help you get what you are looking for.

[How do I sort a swift array containing instances of NSManagedObject subclass by an attribute value (date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577496/how-do-i-sort-a-swift-array-containing-instances-of-nsmanagedobject-subclass-by)

Note: The tableview isn't what you want to sort. It is the array that you are using with the tableview that needs sorted.

Comment: exactly the array i want to sort. I will check the link and give you my feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have array of dates than you can sort by comparing the date, here is the example.....

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let dates = [
            NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1453648103),
            NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1453238129),
            NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1453438129),
            NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1453538129)
        ]
        print(dates)
        print(dates.sort({ $0.isLessThanDate($1) }))

    }
}
extension NSDate {

    func isLessThanDate(dateToCompare: NSDate) -> Bool {
        //Declare Variables
        var isLess = false

    //Compare Values
        if self.compare(dateToCompare) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending {
            isLess = true
        }

        //Return Result
        return isLess
    }
}
```