# Sort Array of NSDates swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, date, nsdate

I have an array of NSDates in swift. The dates are only hours and minutes. I have tried

```
times.sortInPlace({ $0.date.compare($1.date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending })
```

but I get an error "Static member 'date' cannot be used on instance of type 'NSDate' and I get the same error with the 1970 attempt as well.

Comment: You can look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577496/how-do-i-sort-a-swift-array-containing-instances-of-nsmanagedobject-subclass-by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit/update:

Swift 3 or later `NSDate` is now `Date` and it conforms to `Comparable` protocol. Mutating method `sortInPlace` has also been renamed to `sort`:

```
times.sort()
```

---

You are trying to access NSDate date property. Try like this:

```
times.sortInPlace({ $0.compare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending })
```