# PageMenu how to add view controllers dynamically (programmatically)?

Tags: ios, swift

I want my app to look like the image below.

I am using [PageMenu](https://github.com/alimir1/PageMenu) to acomplish this result. The data is fetcehd from a web API. I want to dynamically create view controllers based on the number of days that the web API responds with so that each day can have a view controller so that it can display schedule for that day. How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reading from the link you provided yourself it has:

```
// Array to keep track of controllers in page menu
var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []

// Create variables for all view controllers you want to put in the 
// page menu, initialize them, and add each to the controller array. 
// (Can be any UIViewController subclass)
// Make sure the title property of all view controllers is set
// Example:
var controller : UIViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "controllerNibName", bundle: nil)
controller.title = "SAMPLE TITLE"
controllerArray.append(controller)
```

So what you have to do is : have a function that returns a `[dailyModel]`.
Your dailyModel would look something like this:

```
struct dailyModel {
let programStartingTime : String // 6:45
let item : [item] // [(Maghrib & Isha Prayer, 20, 0),(Ziarat-e-Ashura, 20, 1), ...otherItems...]
}

struct item{
let duration : Int? //minutes
let name : String // Maghrib and Isha prayers
let row : Int? //  0
}
```

Then loop through that `dailyModel` and using its parameters you **instantiate** & **populate** viewcontroller and then **`append`** each of them as the tutorial is doing.

This isn't the best code but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: @AliMir or perhaps your items could have **actual times** ie *6:15 PM* (instead of duration and row) and then sort (using something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34800848/5175709)) your `item`s based on time and list them. I haven't worked with dates before, but I'm assuming the webAPI returns in a string format which you would later have to convert into `NSDate`s and then sort/them if it's in a dictionary format, if your JSON is in an Array format then you have nothing to worry about and you can just loop through and print an item's time and name...

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a loop add same controller multiple times. i created `addPageMenu` function. call it when you get the response.

```
func addPageMenu(count: Int) {

 var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []

  for i in count {

  var controller : UIViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "controllerNibName", bundle: nil)
  if i == 0 {
  controller.title = "SUNDAY"
  } else if i == 1 {
   controller.title = "MONDAY"
  }...

  controllerArray.append(controller)

 }

  let pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

// Lastly add page menu as subview of base view controller view
// or use pageMenu controller in you view hierachy as desired
  self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)
 }
```