# Compile error when sorting swift Array by member value

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, swift

I'm trying to sort by an attribute of a class, but I continually get `Could not find member` errors on my attribute in the sort function. I started by reading several similar questions such as [this one,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value) but I still feel I'm doing something incorrectly.

Can anyone explain what would cause this?

My Sorting Attempt:

[image: My Sort Code]

My class with startTime attribute:

[image: My Class]

I've also tried several different ways of declaring the `airings` object. All result in the same "could not find member 'startTime'" error message.

- `var airings: [Airing] = [Airing]()`
- `var airings = [Airing]()`
- `var airings = Array<Airing>()`
- `var airings: Array<Airing> = []`

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: Can you replace the screenshots with actual code please?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the answer I needed from the duplicate found my Martin R. Sorry I didn't catch that one in my search.