# Sort array of custom objects by date swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, parse-platform, nsdate

I have a custom object "Meeting" I am adding all the objects in an array. What I want to do is sort the array from Meeting.meetingDate.

I'm also using Parse, I have two queries and putting the results into one array.

I am able to add the data to "meetingData", but not sort it.

Can anyone help with this?

So my array is:

```
var meetingsData = [Meeting]()
```

The Meeting class is:

```
public class Meeting: PFObject, PFSubclassing
{

  @NSManaged public var meetingTitle: String?
  @NSManaged public var meetingLocation: String?
  @NSManaged public var meetingNotes: String?
  @NSManaged public var meetingDuration: String?
  @NSManaged public var createdBy: User?
  @NSManaged public var meetingTime: NSDate?
  @NSManaged public var meetingDate: NSDate?

}
```

The contents of the array is like so:

```
<Meeting: 0x125edd040, objectId: xIqx7MoRd6, localId: (null)> {
createdBy = "<PFUser: 0x125d627c0, objectId: RKCWJRj84O>";
meetingDate = "2015-08-29 17:07:12 +0000";
meetingDuration = "2 hours 2 mins";
meetingLocation = 4th Floor;
meetingNotes = With Investors;
meetingTime = "2015-08-24 09:00:17 +0000";
meetingTitle = Meeting with Investors;
}
<Meeting: 0x125ed95f0, objectId: tz4xx5p9jB, localId: (null)> {
createdBy = "<PFUser: 0x125d627c0, objectId: RKCWJRj84O>";
meetingDate = "2015-08-23 23:00:00 +0000";
meetingDuration = "1 hour";
meetingLocation = "Emirates Stadium, London";
meetingNotes = "Football";
meetingTime = "2000-01-01 20:00:00 +0000";
meetingTitle = "Liverpool V Arsenal";
}
<Meeting: 0x125ed95f0, objectId: tz4xx5p9jB, localId: (null)> {
createdBy = "<PFUser: 0x125d627c0, objectId: RKCWJRj84O>";
meetingDate = "2015-09-23 23:00:00 +0000";
meetingDuration = "1 hour";
meetingLocation = "Library";
meetingNotes = "Dev Team";
meetingTime = "2000-01-01 10:00:00 +0000";
meetingTitle = "Code Review";
}
```

I have tried to do this [Swift how to sort array of custom objects by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value) but it doesn't work

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For **Swift 4, Swift 5**

Sorting by timestamp

```
values.sorted(by: { $0.meetingDateTimestamp > $1. meetingDateTimestamp })
```

Answer (score 54):

`NSDate` can't be compared with `<` directly. You can use `NSDate`'s [`compare`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare:) method, like in the following code:

```
meetingsData.sort({ $0.meetingDate.compare($1.meetingDate) == .OrderedAscending })
```

In the above code you can change the order of the sort using the [`NSComparisonResult`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparisonResult) enum, that in Swift is implemented like the following:

```
enum NSComparisonResult : Int {
   case OrderedAscending
   case OrderedSame
   case OrderedDescending
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks.. i' using `sortInPlace` for mutablity

Answer (score 26):

For **Swift 3**

```
meetingsData.sort(by: { $0.meetingDate.compare($1.meetingDate) == .orderedAscending})
```

OR

As dates are now directly comparable in **Swift 3**, For example.

```
   let firstDate = Date()
   let secondDate = Date()

   if firstDate < secondDate {    
   } else if firstDate == secondDate {        
   } else if firstDate > secondDate {        
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, Ramkrishna. Looks like the syntax has updated a little since your post... meetingsData.sorted(by: { $0.meetingDate.compare($1.meetingDate) == .orderedAscending})