# Swift: Loop through objects and their certain variables

Tags: swift

I have a class called "Man". One of a variable of Man is the "height" of the person.

I have for example 10 objects of "Man" with different values for the height parameter and now I want to order these objects by the height. How can I achieve this?

```
var allMan:[Man] = [Man]()
    for currentMan in allMan {
        //Something to do
    }
```

Comment: Seems to be answered [in this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24130092/758831).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that `allMen` is the array to be sorted:

```
var allMen = [Man]()
```

Then, suppose you initialised the array with 10 values. After that you can get sorted `allMen` in descending order:

```
var allSortedMen = allMen.sort { $0.height > $1.height }
```

**Explanation**:

You should pass a function/closure of the type `isOrderedBefore: (Self.Generator.Element, Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool`

```
let sortedAllMen = allMen.sort { (first: Men, second: Men -> Bool in
    return first.height > second.height  
    // or return first.height < second.height for ascending sort order
}
```