# Swift Custom NSMutableArray Sorting

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom NSMutableArray and i want to sort it; I've looked over the internet but nothing solve my problem. what I have is the following `Locations.swift`

```
import UIKit

class Location: NSObject {
    var id:String = String()
    var name:String = String()
    var distance:Float = Float()
}
```

then I create a Mutable Array from this class in my `ViewController.swift`

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController{
    var locations: NSMutableArray!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locations = NSMutableArray()
        locations = SqLite.getInstnace().getLocations()//get values from DB، objects of Location
    }

}
```

how I can sort `locations` by the `distance` value??

Comment: there's an easier solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make `location` an array of `Location` objects, and then sorting becomes easy with `sortInPlace`.

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController{
    var locations = [Location]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locations = SqLite.getInstnace().getLocations().flatMap { $0 as? Location }
    }
}
```

Now you can sort locations like this:

```
locations.sortInPlace { $0.distance < $1.distance }
```

Comment: Value of type 'NSMutableArray' has no member 'sortInPlace'

Comment: Did you replace `var locations: NSMutableArray!` with `var locations = [Location]()`?

Comment: thank you :) it worked, I didn't pay attention at first, you saved a lot of time for me

Comment: Also worth mentioning @KhalilRumman you should avvoid using Foundation type objects unless you MUST use them. Stick to the Swift object types.

Answer (score 3):

You could always use the built in `sort` function:

```
    let locations = SqLite.getInstnace().getLocations().sort({
        return ($0 as! Location).distance < ($1 as! Location).distance
    })
```

if `SqLite.getInstnace().getLocations()` return an array as [Location] and not a NSArray then you could just do this since it will already know the elements types:

```
    let locations = SqLite.getInstnace().getLocations().sort({
        return $0.distance < $1.distance
    })
```

This should return a sorted array in ascending order if you want descending just use `>` instead.

Also, there is really no need to use `NSMutableArrays` in Swift. Just use `[Location]`.

Edit:

`NSMutableArray` can be used in swift but it considered objective-c like where as using `[OBJECT_TYPE]` is conventional for swift.

Take a look at the Swift 2 [book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) array segment. None of the examples use `NSArray` or `NSMutable` array.

By declaring something with `var` in swift makes it mutable where as `let` makes something immutable

Comment: can you explain to me why I don't need to use NSMutableArrays in swift?? just to keep it in my mind for the future

Comment: `NSMutableArray` is very object-Cish where as  `var locations:[Location]` is more swifty and it is also mutable. If you take a look at the Swift 2 book they don't use anything like NSArray. It's just convention not law. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: Also in the book, `Swift’s Array type is bridged to Foundation’s NSArray class`