# Swift 2 TableView Sorting

Tags: ios, sorting, swift2, tableview

I have an iOS project I'm working on in Xcode 7 using Swift 2.  I have an `array` called `details` with a dictionary which includes a `String` and an `Int` value.  The `Int` is called `cellOrder` in the `Class` and the idea is to sort the `details` `array` in a `TableView` with a sort based on the `cellOrder` `Int` value.

The array shows the `String` values which are names.  I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value) to try and implement this into my project with no success.

Here is my array:

```
// Array of data for the TableView
var details = [ProjectDetails]()
```

Here is my `TableView` Code:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return details.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = details[indexPath.row]        

    return cell

}
```

How do I do the sort and where would I put the code, `ViewDidLoad()` or maybe `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

**UPDATE**:

My `ViewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // TableView Sorting
    details.sortInPlace({$0.cellOrder < $1.cellOrder})

    tableView.delegate = self

    ...

}
```

**Update 2**:

My `ProjectDetails` `class` for the `array` data is:

```
import UIKit

class ProjectDetails: NSObject, NSCoding {

    // MARK: Properties

    var fileName: String
    var cellOrder: Int

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort the array you would just do 
`details.sortInPlace({$0.cellOrder < $1.cellOrder})`
in viewDidLoad, or you could use 
`details.sort({$0.cellOrder < $1.cellOrder})[indexPath.row]`
in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but that could prove dangerous if you do not keep track of your array.

One will sort the array in place, one will return a sorted immutable array.

If you insist on sorting immutably (has its pros and cons beyond this scope) assign it to another array and use that in your logic.

Comment: I added a new item to the array with a `cellOrder` of 0 and reloaded the `TableView` but it kept the old sort based on the `IndexPath`.  It was the only one with a 0 as the `cellOrder`.

Comment: Once you sort, you need to call `reloadData()` on the UITableView.  This is not necessary after the sort in viewDidLoad, since this happens before the tableview gets populated.

Comment: I put it in my `ViewDidLoad`.  It was the first item in it.

Comment: Please update your code in the original post to avoid having the debug lost in the comments.  I'll have a look there.

Answer (score 1):

You must sort the itens in this array `details[]`, after that, you can call `tableView.reloadData()` to reload the info.

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you must just take the data to fill the cell, so NO SORT THERE!

Sort anywhere else, before call the function to reload.