# Swift - Sorting NSMutableArray with objects in it

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsmutablearray, columnsorting

I have a `fruit` object in swift with

```
var title: String? 
var desc: String?
```

variables

I have it in a `fruitsArray` which is an NSMutableArray.

I want to sort out these fruit objects alphabetically depending on their title. I need to do this both ascending and descending.

I have tried doing the following:

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =
        [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title"
    ascending:YES
    selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [fruitsArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

But it does not work at all, just heaps of errors.

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance friends.

Comment: Or maybe a better fit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value

Comment: @luk2302 no. I have had a look at that.

Comment: do you know that the code sample you provide is in Objective-C?

Comment: Oh... Well there we go that is part of the problem :O

Comment: The code is in swift, not obj-c. So there is no answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `sort` function with a block:

```
struct Fruit {
    var title: String
    var desc: String
}

var fruits = [Fruit]()
fruits.append(Fruit(title: "a", desc: "b"))
fruits.append(Fruit(title: "c", desc: "d"))


let sorted = fruits.sort() { $0.title > $1.title }
sorted
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

it should be sortUsingDescriptors: not sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:

Comment: You might tell him what's the difference. Each has its uses.