# Swift - How does one sort an array by internal integer property in the most efficient way

Tags: arrays, swift, performance, sorting, integer

**Swift 2.3**

Alright folks. Assuming i have a Class named `Post`, and array of Posts, `[Post]`.

```
class Posts 
{
  var message : String?
  var scheduledTime : Int?
}
....
var myPosts = [Posts]()...(500 objects)
```

How can i, in the most **efficient/performance wise** way(let's assume i have 500 `Post` objects inside my array), to sort our `[Post]` array, by our `scheduledTime`(Int) property?

Was always curious on how to approach this kind of questions. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift how to sort array of custom objects by property value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value)

Comment: This code worries me. `class`, `var` and implicitly wrapped optionals are their own code smells, but put together... not good!

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Thanks for pointing out! I was in a rush, didn't quiet see those small mistakes, And thanks for the link, I guess i haven't search the right search terms. Have a great day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`sort(_:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/MutableCollectionType/#func--sort_) with a closure that compares the first argument's `scheduledTime` to the second's.

```
let sortedPosts = myPosts.sort{ $0.scheduledTime < $1.scheduledTime }
```

Comment: OP asked for Swift 2.3, but I figured I'd add that it's been renamed to `sorted(by:...)` in Swift 3

Comment: @Bek Thanks. I don't think it'll matter though, I suspect this question will be closed and deleted soon enough

Comment: Hey Alexander I can't close it with anwers tho. I'll just wait for the moderator to close it. Thanks! Have a great day :)

Comment: @RoiMulia Can't you just close without moderator? It's usually better not to delete so others searching the same phrases would find here.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate. When it reached 5 votes (currently at 3), the question will be closed, and has a link to the duplicate post.