# iOS Swift 3 Sorting Array into Ascending Order

Tags: ios, sorting, swift3, nsarray

In our app we are sorting an NSArray in ascending order by using its first_name key. In Swift 2.3 We have used code like this

```
let descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "first_name", ascending: true)
self.ArrayDetails = self.ArrayDetails.sortedArray(using: [descriptor])
```

Now We Are Migrating Code To Swift 3. And We Getting Error Like

```
'sortedArray' produces '[Any]', not the expected contextual result type 'NSArray'
```

Comment: how you have declared ArrayDetails ?

Comment: change this self.ArrayDetails = self.ArrayDetails.sortedArray(using: [descriptor]) to this - self.ArrayDetails = self.ArrayDetails.sortedArray(using: [descriptor]) as! NSArray

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24130092/5085393