# Firebase Sort array of class by value

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase. In my app, I get a child value by passing in a bottleID and get the details for that value from the snapshot. I then assign the details to an object of `MyCollection_Class` and add it to an array. After getting every single bottle value, I want to sort that array using the `created_at` tag before reloading the table view. Please advise me on how to sort the array of objects by a specific instance variable.

```
let Collection = MyCollection_Class()
FireBaseConstants.AUCTIONS_REF.child(bottleID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
    if !(snap.value is NSNull) {
        Collection.id = bottle_dict["id"] as? String
        Collection.item_number = bottle_dict["item_number"] as? Int
        Collection.created_at = bottle_dict["created_at"] as? String
        if !(self.MyCollectionsIDArr.contains(Collection.id! as String)) {
             self.MyCollectionsArr.append(Collection)
             self.MyCollectionsIDArr.append(Collection.id!)
             // I want to sort the MyCollectionsArr using created_at here
             self.tbl_Latest.reloadData()
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you show the sample value of `created_at` because it is of `String` type, so you need to show us the format of the date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift how to sort array of custom objects by property value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can just retrieve the data already sorted from Firebase by using

> queryOrderedByChild.

An example would be:

```
ref.child(bottleID).queryOrderedByChild("created_at").queryEqualToValue(0).observe  SingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snap in
    print("snap \(snap)")
    expectation.fulfill()
})
```