# How to sort array of custom objects by customised status value in swift 3?

Tags: arrays, sorting, object, swift3

lets say we have a custom class named orderFile and this class contains three properties.

```
class orderFile  {
    var name = String()
    var id = Int()
    var status = String()
}
```

a lot of them stored into an array

```
var aOrders : Array = []

var aOrder = orderFile()
aOrder.name = "Order 1"
aOrder.id = 101
aOrder.status = "closed"
aOrders.append(aOrder)

var aOrder = orderFile()
aOrder.name = "Order 2"
aOrder.id = 101
aOrder.status = "open"
aOrders.append(aOrder)

var aOrder = orderFile()
aOrder.name = "Order 2"
aOrder.id = 101
aOrder.status = "cancelled"
aOrders.append(aOrder)

var aOrder = orderFile()
aOrder.name = "Order 2"
aOrder.id = 101
aOrder.status = "confirmed" 
aOrders.append(aOrder)
```

Question is: How will I sort them based on status according to open, confirm, close and cancelled?

Comment: refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24130026/6521116)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to provide a value that will yield the appropriate ordering when compared in the sort function.

For example:

```
extension orderFile
{    
    var statusSortOrder: Int 
        { return ["open","confirmed","closed","cancelled"].index(of: status) ?? 0 }
}

let sortedOrders = aOrders.sorted{$0.statusSortOrder < $1. statusSortOrder}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was exactly looking for this solution.

Comment: Best solution so far, crystal clear

Answer (score 2):

In your code you should make an array to store each aOrder with aOrders.append(aOrder) at each aOrder defination.

Then sort it with below code, refor **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24130026/6521116)** for more.

```
aOrders.sorted({ $0.status > $1.status })
```

Comment: Thanks. 
But how could these way it will sorted according to open, confirm, close and cancelled? How it will know I want to sort like this?

Comment: this will sort by compare these string

Answer (score 0):

The answer for swift 3 is as following

Ascending:

```
aOrders = aOrders.sorted(by: 
                 {(first: orderFile, second: orderFile) -> Bool in
                   first.status > second.status
                 }
              )
```

Descending:

```
aOrders = aOrders.sorted(by: 
                 {(first: orderFile, second: orderFile) -> Bool in
                   first.status < second.status
                 }
              )
```