# Sort array of objects into ascending order

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, anyobject

I have an array of objects. Each object has a key "username".

Is there a swift way of sorting this array of objects into ascending order?

```
(array(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "username") as? String)!
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24130026/335858

Comment: Accept answer please, to let others to find it faster. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
yourArray.sorted({ $0.username < $1.username})
```