# How to sort NSMutableArray that contains object of type Modal?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, nsmutablearray

I’ve an NSMutableArray (say `accountListArray`). The content of array is Model (say `BankAccountModel` with property `defaultAcc - Y/N`).

Now I want to **sort the content of accountListArray based on default property** i.e. `all account that is defaultAcc enabled (Y) should be on top.`

```
class BankAccountModel: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance: BankAccountModel = BankAccountModel()

    var defaultAcc = "" // Y or N
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: `Swift` and `NSMutableArray` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value ?

Comment: can  you add that model class so we can give you specific answer.

Comment: can you provide Model?

Comment: @Jaydeep : Check..question is updated

Comment: @KKRocks : Model added in question

Comment: default is keyword . you declare as variable .

Comment: @KKRocks : Now check

Comment: try my answer .

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

**Create Model property as below**

```
class BankAccountModel: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance: BankAccountModel = BankAccountModel()
    var isDefault: Bool = false

  // assign value
   if let objDefault = dictionary["default"] {
            isDefault = (objDefault as! String) ==  "Y" ? true : false
        }

   // var default = "" // Y or N
}
```

**Sort as below**

```
self.arrOfModels.sort {
     return $0.isDefault && !$1.isDefault // isSelected is your flag . you need to change with your flag 
}
```

**OR**

Another Solution with string

```
self.arrModels.sort {
                        return ($0. defaultAcc == "Y") && ($1. defaultAcc == "N")
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example. It will sort array and after sort person with name 2 and person with name 4 will be in top of the array

```
class People{
    var name = ""
    var isMale:Bool = false

    init(name:String,isMale:Bool){
        self.name = name
        self.isMale = isMale
    }
}

var person1 = People(name: "1",isMale: false)
var person2 = People(name: "2",isMale: true)
var person3 = People(name: "3",isMale: false)
var person4 = People(name: "4",isMale: true)

var array = [person1,person2,person3,person4]

array.sort() { Int(NSNumber(value:($0.isMale))) > Int(NSNumber(value:($1.isMale))) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the answers above. You can define your model as Comparable, then implement your own >, <, == protocol:

For example:

```
class BankAccountModel: Comparable { //or struct
    var accountHolder: String = ""
    var balance: Decimal?
    var enabled: Bool = false

    init(holder: String, balance: Decimal, enabled: Bool) {
        self.accountHolder = holder
        self.balance = balance
        self.enabled = enabled
    }

    static func == (lhs: BankAccountModel, rhs: BankAccountModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.enabled == rhs.enabled
    }

    static func > (lhs: BankAccountModel, rhs: BankAccountModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.enabled || (!lhs.enabled && !rhs.enabled)
    }

    static func < (lhs: BankAccountModel, rhs: BankAccountModel) -> Bool {
        return rhs.enabled || (!rhs.enabled && !lhs.enabled)
    }
}

let account1 = BankAccountModel(holder: "Holder 1", balance: Decimal(10.0), enabled: true)
let account2 = BankAccountModel(holder: "Holder 2", balance: Decimal(20.3), enabled: false)
let account3 = BankAccountModel(holder: "Holder 3", balance: Decimal(-1.0), enabled: false)
let account4 = BankAccountModel(holder: "Holder 4", balance: Decimal(0.0), enabled: true)

var allAccounts = [account1, account2, account3, account4]

allAccounts.sort(by: {return $0 > $1})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

Hope will work for you.

```
let sortedArr = accountListArray.sorted(by: {
    let item1 = $0 as! BankAccountModel
    let item2 = $1 as! BankAccountModel

    if item1.defaultAcc > item2.defaultAcc {
        return true
    }
    return false
})
```