# When to call function that sorts Array in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I made a function that sorts an Array and reorders a TableView (I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value?noredirect=1&lq=1)). I populate the array through an API.

When or where is best to call the sorting function? When I call it from ViewDidLoad or ViewDidAppear the Array is still empty, so nothing happens.

```
func sort(){

    self.myArray = myArray.sorted(by: {$0.rank < $1.rank })
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: When does the array that needs to be sorted get populated in the first place ?

Comment: simple write this code when you want to use

Comment: When you never call your sort function the array not nil, right ?

Comment: What is the crash error?

Comment: post the crash log

Comment: Nothing happens so when I want to print the first element of the array, the app crashes because it is not populated yet. This is the crash error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: @A.Munzer yes, is not nil

Comment: @humblePilgrim I am not sure, I wish I know this.. I wish I know when it finishes populating so I can sort it. Is a tableview in a UIViewController, and it loads when opening the app

Comment: Ok.. what is the source of your data ? Do you get it from a web service ?

Comment: @humblePilgrim yes, is from a web service.  I would like to know when is the tableview completely loaded.  If I try to sort it pushing a button, it works, but how can I avoid that? thanks a lot!!

Comment: If you know when you have got the data, then you can just check if the array is valid (not nil),  sort the array  and call reload data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what worked was calling the sorting function just after the array is created and reloading the tableview.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
getData()
}

func getData() {     

 Alamofire.request(apiURL).validate().responseJSON() { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    let users = json.arrayValue
                    for item in users{
                        let temp = User(json: item)
                        self.myArray.append(temp)
                    }

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                    self.sort()     //<---here

                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }

func sort(){

    self.myArray = myArray.sorted(by: {$0.rank < $1.rank })
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your function in **ViewDidLoad** but without reload table view data

```
func sort(){
    self.myArray = myArray.sorted(by: {$0.rank < $1.rank })    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a `tableView` problem, check your delegate, data source and IB connections, nothing is wrong with the sorting as long as the array is not = nil (make sure of that)

Answer (score 0):

Check you crash log, nothing wrong with this code

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're using this sort for, so this may not be useful, but you can add a nil check at the top and init a new empty array if it the array is nil.

```
func sort(){
    if self.myArray == nil {
        self.myArray = [YourArrayType]()
    }
    self.myArray = myArray.sorted(by: {$0.rank < $1.rank })
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

You can also declare the array optional (`private var myArray: [Your ArrayType]?`) or initialize it upon declaration (`private var myArray = [YourArrayType]()`). The first lets you call any method on the array with a `?` and it won't execute if the array is nil, the other one makes sure the array is not nil but rather just empty.

Comment: thank you! I tried the first one and still nothing happens with the tableview. Is not nil, but empty. It seems that it needs time to load. And I am doing this test with only 3 elements on the tableview, is not that big..

Comment: @Maruta I don't know how you load your tableview data, but a very common way is to load some data from an API and use it to populate the tableview. If something like that is your case you can call `tableView.reloadData()` after finishing your data fetch to signal the tableview to call all its delegate functions again.

Comment: yes I am using an API and I also reloadData after data fetch. But where would you call the func sort() ? Everywhere I call it (except from an IBAction button) the array is not filled yet