# Reordering Arrays within Arrays using the First Index Swift

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift3

I am trying to sort an array as shown:

```
 var arrayTst = [
    [12443, "Starbucks", "Coffee1", "Coffee11", "Tea1", "Drinks1"],
    [12495, "Coffee Bean", "Coffee2", "Tea2", "Cookies2"],
    [13000, "GroceryMarket", "Tea3", "Bubble Tea3", "Shaved Ice3", "Mangoes"], 
    [10000, "Costco", "Soda4", "Salads4", "Pizza4"]
]
```

How can I sort this list from least to greatest using the first index(which shows the distance)? For example, since I want this array to sort from least to greatest by distance, I would want it to sort to :

```
var arrayTst = [
    [10000, "Costco", "Soda4","Salads4","Pizza4"],
    [12443, "Starbucks", "Coffee1","Coffee11", "Tea1", "Drinks1"],
    [12495, "Coffee Bean", "Coffee2", "Tea2","Cookies2"],
    [13000, "GroceryMarket", "Tea3", "Bubble Tea3", "Shaved Ice3", "Mangoes"]
]
```

The distance was calculated using .distance(from: currentLocation) and placing into the array via for loop.

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift how to sort array of custom objects by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-consider your data structure. Rather than just an array of `Any`, it looks like you have an array of…

```
struct Store {
    let distance: Double
    let name: String
    let products: [String]
}
```

Then…

```
var arrayTst = [
    Store(distance: 12443, name: "Starbucks", products: ["Coffee11", "Tea1", "Drinks1"]),
    Store(distance: 12495, name: "Coffee Bean", products: ["Coffee2", "Tea2", "Cookies2"]),
    etc…
]

let sortedArray = arrayTst.sorted { $0.distance < $1.distance }
```