# Swift: Order array with same values

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a 2D array with multiples values.

One field on this array is called `group`, let's imagine my array have this order:

```
private var myArray = [
   ArrayModel(
      id: 0,
      name: "Test",
      color: 0,
      img: "img.png",
      group = "myGroup"),
   ArrayModel(
      id: 1,
      name: "Test1",
      color: 0,
      img: "img.png",
      group: "myGroup"),
   ArrayModel(
      id: 2,
      name: "Test2",
      color = 0,
      img = "img.png",
      group = "myGroup3")
   ArrayModel(
      id: 3,
      name: "Test3",
      color: 0,
      img: "img.png",
      group: "myGroup2"),
   ArrayModel(
      id: 4
      name: "Test4"
      color: 0
      img: "img.png"
      group: "myGroup3")
]
```

#### Array Model

```
class ArrayModel: Decodable {

var id: Int
var name: String
var color: Int
var img: String
var group: String

convenience init() {
    self.init()
    id = 0
    name = ""
    color = 0
    img = ""
    group = ""
}

init(id: Int, name: String, color: Int, img: String, group: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.color = color
    self.img = img
    self.group = group
}

}
```

How can I move my `myArray[2]` to be in `myArray[1]` ?

### My desired output is :

```
let myArray = [
   ArrayModel(
      id: 0,
      name: "Test",
      color: 0,
      img: "img.png",
      group: "myGroup")
   ]
   [1] => same shema, but group => "myGroup"
   [2] => same shema, but group => "myGroup2"
   [3] => same shema, but group => "myGroup2"
   [4] => same shema, but group => "myGroup3"
]
```

I tried this :

```
myArray.sorted(by: { $0.group < $1.group })
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please can you show your exact input and desired output? (as well as any code you've tried?)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking -  a (deleted) answer correctly showed how to move `myArray[2]` to  `myArray[1]`

Comment: It is edited now. Sorry for the wrong formulation, it's a bit hard to explain myself on problems like this :-)

Comment: Sorry, I may just be a noob here, but what's a shema??

Comment: @Adi219 Same array with keys, values changes, in this case, only group change

Comment: You say it's a 2D array but it looks more like an array of dictionaries or structs. Could you show us some real code instead of this pseudo code?

Comment: I've edited your question to show my understanding of what `myArray` initially looks like. Am I correct? (If not, feel free to roll back the edit)

Comment: @RomainSickenberg Please show declaration of myArray

Comment: @Adi219 Thanks, it's almost correct, but I edited it, I will post some code

Comment: This is not a 2D array.

Comment: The code with which you initialise your array is wrong. You should be initialising the structs, not an array with a semi-JSON dictionary containing the arguments of the struct.

Comment: @NiravD Actually, they don't need the `by: ... ` bit. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24130058/7908770

Comment: @Adi219 if you write closure in `()` then you need to use first parameter argument `by`

Comment: @NiravD See my answer (you don't need `()` ).

Comment: @Adi219 It doesn't related to add by or not its related with `sort` and `sorted` method

Comment: @NiravD I'm not quite sure about what you mean, but it's definitely relevant here as the OP isn't using `sorted` appropriately here.

Comment: @regina_fallangi I'm 100% sure this is wrong, I append my array like a normal array, with this :  `JSONDecoder().decode(jsonStruct.self, from: json)`

Comment: @RomainSickenberg without the piece of code you just posted, that would be wrong. Make sure to always post all of your code.

Comment: I will, thanks @regina_fallangi :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
myArray.sort { $0.group < $1.group }
```

The `.sort(by: ...)` isn't what you need here, as you want to **modify** `myArray` (by sorting it). To do that, you have to omit the `by:...`.

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24130058/7908770) :)

Comment: This doesn't make sense `sorted` return sorted array its not mutable method

Comment: Check the apple doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted it will return sorted array you need to store the result, sort is the mutating method https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296801-sort

Comment: @NiravD Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value/24130058#24130058

Comment: If you check the answer it is using `sort` method not the `sorted` check apple doc

Comment: @NiravD Yep, you're right! What you've been saying makes sense. Edited my answer :)

Comment: No, sorted was right, with `sort` I have an error `Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'subscript'`

Answer (score 1):

This may help you to sorted by Case Sensitive but your `myArray` should be `mutable`. ex : `var myArray`

```
myArray = myArray.sorted(by: { $0.group.localizedCompare($1.group) == .orderedAscending})
```