# How to order an object by a parameter that is an array of numbers (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to order an object by a parameter. But this parameter is not a value but an array of values.

```
class MyObject:{
    var arrayOfDoubles: [Double]
}
```

I´ve solved how to order the param `arrayOfDoubles`

```
self.arrayOfDoubles.sorted(by: >)
```

My problem now is how to order the array `myObjects` by the param `arrayOfDoubles`

```
myObjects: [MyObject]
```

I´ve tried this solution, but it only works when the param is a number, not an array of numbers
    `myObjects.sorted(by: { $0.arrayOfDoubles > $1.arrayOfDoubles })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift how to sort array of custom objects by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value)

Comment: What is the condition for sorting?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri decresing

Comment: What do you mean by that? It has an array, how can an array be decreasing? Elements in the array can be decreasing.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I think is not. Because that post is how to order an object by a param that is a number. My param is array of number. I´ve tried that solution but does not compile

Comment: Array 1 [100, 40] is bigger than Array 2 [20, 50]. Is this clear?

Comment: You mean the sum of the elements in the array?

Comment: How are you defining what the sort is? The above question answers what you're trying to do, the only thing that isn't answered in there is how you define which array should appear before the other because there's not really a defined sort for a comparison like this.

Comment: @jlowe the condition should be "Comparing each index of the arrays, until an index value is bigger than the other. That is the condition. 

e.g: [20, 40] is bigger than [10,0] and [20, 40] is bigger than [20, 30]. All the individual arrays are always sorted decreasingly also.

Comment: Your "doubles" should be a custom struct. Also you need to explain what "comparing each index" means; I still don't know how to tell whether one double is bigger than another double, and if I don't know, I can't tell a computer how to know.

Comment: Also you say "decreasing" but your code says `>` which means increasing. So it is unclear even what sort direction you want.

Comment: > is decreasing. But I agree that he show some of his examples sorted increasingly

Answer (score 1):

This might not be exactly what you want, because I can't figure out what you want (and I'm not sure you do either). But in general your problems will be over if you define a custom struct and make it Equatable and Comparable. Then you can just sort using `>` or `<` directly, like this:

```
struct Pair : Comparable {
    let ix1:Int
    let ix2:Int
    init(_ ix1: Int, _ ix2:Int) {
        self.ix1 = ix1; self.ix2 = ix2
    }
    static func ==(lhs:Pair, rhs:Pair) -> Bool {
        return lhs.ix1 == rhs.ix1 && lhs.ix2 == rhs.ix2
    }
    static func <(lhs:Pair, rhs:Pair) -> Bool {
        return lhs.ix1 < rhs.ix1 && lhs.ix2 < rhs.ix2
    }
}

let array1 = [Pair(1,3), Pair(10,11), Pair(0,1)]
let array2 = array1.sorted(by:>)
// [{ix1 10, ix2 11}, {ix1 1, ix2 3}, {ix1 0, ix2 1}]
```

As I say, that's only an example; tweak it so that it says what you mean (if you even know what you mean).

For instance, if this Pair is now to be a property of another object type Obj, that's trivial in just the same way:

```
struct Obj {
    let pair : Pair
}
let array3 = [Obj(pair:Pair(1,3)), Obj(pair:Pair(10,11)), Obj(pair:Pair(0,1))]
let array4 = array3.sorted {$0.pair > $1.pair}
```

I believe that's the sort of language your question says you'd like to use...