# Value of type 'Int' has no member 'intValue'

Tags: arrays, swift, int

I have a `message` array. Each message has a `timestamp` property that's an `Int`. I'm trying to sort out the array based on the most recent date, but I'm getting an error saying:

> Value of type 'Int' has no member 'intValue'

```
self.messages.sort(by: { (message1, message2) -> Bool in
     return message1.timestamp!.intValue > message2.timestamp!.intValue
})
```

Comment: `return message1.timestamp! > message2.timestamp!` make sure timestamp it is not nil

Comment: @LeoDabus oh, yeah. That's right. This works. Please, add it as an answer so  I can accept it. Thank you

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift how to sort array of custom objects by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value)

Comment: Side note: Can a message lack the timestamp? If not, make `timestamp` non-optional.

Comment: @vadian it is an optional, but I know it always has a value. I just tried to sort it the wrong way. Thank you for your time though. I appreciate it.

Comment: If you *know it always has a value* make it non-optional. Non-optionals cannot crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message it is pretty self explanatory timestamp it is not a `NSNumber` it is an `Int` therefore you can compare them directly. If you are sure the timestamp will never be nil it is better change its declaration to non-optional:

```
messages.sort { $0.timestamp > $1.timestamp }
```