# Sorting of Multidimensional Associative Array by Value (SWIFT)

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, nsdictionary, associative-array

How could I sort the following associative array:

```
[
  ["name": "Zone A", "type": "1"], 
  ["name": "Zone B", "type": "2"], 
  ["name": "Zone C", "type": "1"],
  ["name": "Zone D", "type": "3"], 
  ["name": "Zone E", "type": "2"], 
  ["name": "Zone F", "type": "3"],
  ["name": "Zone G", "type": "1"], 
  ["name": "Zone H", "type": "2"]
]
```

to result in the following - **sorted by TYPE**:

```
[
  ["name": "Zone A", "type": "1"], 
  ["name": "Zone C", "type": "1"],
  ["name": "Zone G", "type": "1"], 
  ["name": "Zone B", "type": "2"], 
  ["name": "Zone E", "type": "2"], 
  ["name": "Zone H", "type": "2"]
  ["name": "Zone D", "type": "3"],       
  ["name": "Zone F", "type": "3"],
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't sort an associative array. It makes no sense. You copy elements to a regular array and sort it.

Comment: You should have that array as an array of a struct with name and type instead of a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sort`

```
var a = [
  ["name": "Zone A", "type": "1"], 
  ["name": "Zone B", "type": "2"], 
  ["name": "Zone C", "type": "1"],
  ["name": "Zone D", "type": "3"], 
  ["name": "Zone E", "type": "2"], 
  ["name": "Zone F", "type": "3"],
  ["name": "Zone G", "type": "1"], 
  ["name": "Zone H", "type": "2"]
]

a.sort { (v1, v2) -> Bool in
    return v1["type"]! < v2["type"]!
}

//or:
//a.sort { $0["type"]! < $1["type"]! }

print("\(a)")
```

See also: [Swift how to sort array of custom objects by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value)

And `sort` & `sorted`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296801-sort

- `sort`: Sorts the collection in place.
- `sorted`: Returns the elements of the sequence, sorted.

Comment: Thank you. That's brilliant, shawn. I should elaborate, for clarity, that the structure in the OP is actually an array, and not a dictionary (mis-tagged). Accordingly, this **sort** solution works perfectly. Always foggy about these terminologies.

Comment: PHP uses the concept `Associative Array` more and Swift uses the concept `Dictionary` more, they are the same. See here: http://iosdose.com/wp/2017/08/22/swift-dictionary/ .  And about `sort` and `sorted`: the `sort` does sort on the original array and changes it.  `sorted` doesn't change the original array and return a newly created sorted array.