# How to sort an array by one of the elements?

Tags: swift, collections

I created an alias - **typealias frequenciesSymbol = (String, Double)**. 
I created an array using an alias as the data type frequenciesSymbol. Then I filled this array with elements, and now I need to sort this array by Double elements. How should I do it?

```
typealias frequenciesSymbol = (String, Double)
```

// WE THINK THE FREQUENCY OF MEETING EACH SYMBOL

```
var frequencies2 = [Double](repeating: 0, count: 33)
for c in outputText.unicodeScalars {
    switch c {
    case "а"..."я":
        frequencies2[Int(c.value - UnicodeScalar("а").value)] += 1
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

// TRANSFER FREQUENCY IN %

```
for i in 0..<(frequencies2.count) {
    frequencies2[i] = (frequencies2[i] * 100) / Double(outputText.count)
}
```

// CREATE AN ARRAY IN WHICH WE FORM THE FREQUENCY IN ACCORDANCE WITH THE SYMBOLS WITH THE SYMBOLS

```
var frequenciesOutputText = [frequenciesSymbol]()
```

// WRITE THE ARRAY OF VALUES OF FREQUENCY ACCORDING TO THE SYMBOL

```
for i in 0..<(frequencies2.count-1) {
    frequenciesOutputText.append((rus[i], Double(frequencies2[i])))
    print("\(rus[i]) - \(frequencies2[i])%")
}
```

//SORT ARRAY BY FREQUENCY VALUES

I want to get something like this

("о", 10.97)%
("е", 8.45)%
("а", 8.01)%
("и", 7.35)%
("н", 6.7)%
("т", 6.26)%
("с", 5.47)%
("р", 4.73)%
("в", 4.54)%
("л", 4.4)%
("к", 3.49)%
("м", 3.21)%
("д", 2.98)%
("п", 2.81)%
("у", 2.62)%
("я", 2.01)%
("ы", 1.9)%
("ь", 1.74)%
("г", 1.7)%
("з", 1.65)%
("б", 1.59)%
("ч", 1.44)%
("й", 1.21)%
("х", 0.97)%
("ж", 0.94)%
("ш", 0.73)%
("ю", 0.64)%
("ц", 0.48)%
("щ", 0.36)%
("э", 0.32)%
("ф", 0.26)%
("ъ", 0.04)%

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/24130026/1187415.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work
consider

```
 frequenciesSymbol = (name: String, value: Double)
 frequenciesSymbol.sorted(by: { $0. value > $1. value })
```