# Get an element from server in asc order based on the particular id

Tags: ios, swift

I get a certain response from the server which looks like so...

```
[
    {
        "theCode": A12345,
        "id": 2980,
        "name": “HELLO”
    },
    {
        "theCode": A12345,
        "id": 2986,
        "name": "HELLO THERE”
    },
    {
        "theCode": A12345,
        "id": 2987,
        "name": "HOW ARE YOU”
    }
]
```

Once the api is called, I store the above data in an array. It is given like so...

```swift
if let myArray = (sdfg["entries"] as? NSMutableArray) {
    print(myArray) 

}
```

I would like the `name` in the above response to be sorted in ascending order based on the id. How can this be achieved...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift how to sort array of custom objects by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let sortedResults = NSMutableArray(myArray.sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)]))
```

Comment: I wanted the resulting sorted array as `NSMutableArray`. But when I do this..`let sortedResults = self.arrResult1.sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)]) as! NSMutableArray` then I get a crash saying `Could not cast value of type 'Swift.__SwiftDeferredNSArray’ to 'NSMutableArray'` @teja_D

Comment: @user13032222 Why do you want it as NSMutableArray?

Comment: Because I'm passing the array to another view controller as NSMutableArray itself.

Comment: You are using swift now so use swift arrays which are easier to maintain.

Comment: Cannot upvote since I have less than 15 reputation @teja_D..:)