# Swift: How to sort cells in tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, sorting, uitableview

I have tableview and array with GuestList attending status. All data is save on Firebase Database.
Also has a button sortBy where when is clicked I need to sort cells by attending status. Ex: Display all guests with attending status.
I'm new in swift.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjKVR.png)

Comment: Don't sort cells, sort the data source array and reload the table view.

Comment: @vadian can you gave me an example how to do that?

Comment: As I have no idea what your data model is this is a generic example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value